# why i cannot access static variable?

Tags: javascript, oop, requirejs

```
define([],function(){


    let Journal = function(list) {
        //static var
        var pilots = [];
        this.findLaynerpilots = function findLaynerpilots(arr) {
            let pilots = arr || pilots
            return pilots.filter(function (item) {
                return item.is_pilot_of_plane
            })

        };
return new Journal;
}
```

Why pilots is not defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to make names different in case of pilots. `let pilots = arr || pilots` looks confusing. You can rename *internal* `pilots` to `pilots_`

Or use `var self=this` to bring proper `pilots`

```
define([],function(){    

    let Journal = function(list) {            
        let self = this;
        self.pilots = [];
        this.findLaynerpilots = function findLaynerpilots(arr) {
            let pilots_ = arr || self.pilots
            return pilots_.filter(function (item) {
                return item.is_pilot_of_plane
            })

        };
return new Journal;
}
```